# How to implement interface for tree

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a tree structure TableOfContents:

```
export interface TableOfContents {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  isExpanded: boolean;
  children: TableOfContents[];
}
```

I need a function for searching an item in array of trees and want to make it generic. So I did the next:

```
export interface TreeNode {
  [key: string]: any;
  children?: TreeNode[];
}

export interface TableOfContents extends TreeNode {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  isExpanded: boolean;
}

export const findInTrees = <TreeType extends TreeNode>(
  trees: TreeType[],
  callback: (el: TreeType) => boolean
): TreeType | null => {
  const tree = trees.find(tree => callback(tree));
  if (tree) {
    return tree;
  }
  for (const tree of trees) {
    if (tree.children) {
      const result = findInTrees(tree.children, callback);
      if (result) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

But have an error `TS2345: Argument of type 'TreeNode[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TreeType[]'.` on the line `const result = findInTrees(tree.children, callback);`

Could you please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `TreeNode` interface, your code says that `children` should be an array of anything that implements `TreeNode`, when really what you mean is that `children` should be an array of the **same type of `TreeNode`**. So, use the `this` type:

```
export interface TreeNode {
  [key: string]: any;
  children?: this[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export type INode<T = any> = T & {
    nodes: Array<INode<T>>;
}



const family: INode<{name?: string}> = {
    name: 'Bogdan',
    nodes: []
};
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for the benefits of this approach over the accepted answer?